# moto unit test EC2 - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, python-unittest

I want to unittest some methods inside my `aws_manager`:

```
class aws_manager:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION_NAME)
        self.running_instances = []

 def launchInstances(self, count: int):

            instances = self.ec2.run_instances(
                ImageId=IMAGE_ID,
                MinCount=count,
                MaxCount=count,
                InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
                KeyName=KEY_NAME,
                SecurityGroupIds=[SECURITY_GROUP_ID]
            )["Instances"][0]
```

my test looks like this:

```
import unittest
import boto3
from moto import mock_ec2
import aws_manager


@mock_ec2
class TestAwsManager(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_launchInstances(self):
        manager = aws_manager.aws_manager()
        manager.launchInstances(2)
        client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='eu-central-1')
        instances = client.describe_instances()
        print(instances)
```

But the instances variable looks like this when printed:

```
{'Reservations': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'fdcdcab1-ae5c-489e-9c33-4637c5dda355', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'amazon.com'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

I also get this error:

```
[ERROR][2022-07-02 22:30:42,452]: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Have I overseen something? Shouldn't `client` contain the instances?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u show me the model fields

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code the mock ec2 and security group id.

```
def ec2():
"""
Returns a mock EC2 resource
"""

with mock_ec2():

    ec2_res = boto3.resource("ec2", region_name="us-west-1")

    ec2_res.create_key_pair(KeyName="your_key")

    yield ec2_res

@pytest.fixture
def security_group_id(ec2):
    """
    Returns a mock EC2 instance
    """
    security_group = ec2.create_security_group(
        GroupName="your_group_name",
        Description="test",
    )
    yield security_group.id
```